# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method retryOnConnectionFailure Error when running Detox Tests with Proguard enabled in React Native 0.66

Tags: android, proguard, detox

When running Detox tests in our Android mobile solution we are getting the following error. This started to happen when we were upgrading from RN 0.64.2 to 0.66.2.  We are running Detox 19.3.1.

```
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: detox.primary
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.feebris, PID: 10124
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method retryOnConnectionFailure(Z)Lh/z$a; in class Lh/z$a; or its super classes (declaration of 'h.z$a' appears in /data/app/~~KiD_HyQgzGz_Bgpxj4D67Q==/com.feebris-QUkKs1ICtsb3GT-tmXzJ9A==/base.apk)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wix.detox.adapters.server.WebSocketClient.connectToServer(WebSocketClient.java:51)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wix.detox.adapters.server.DetoxServerAdapter.connect(DetoxServerAdapter.kt:21)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wix.detox.DetoxMain.doInit(DetoxMain.kt:30)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wix.detox.DetoxMain.access$doInit(DetoxMain.kt:15)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wix.detox.DetoxMain$initActionHandlers$$inlined$with$lambda$1.handle(DetoxMain.kt:52)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wix.detox.adapters.server.ActionsExecutor$executeAction$$inlined$let$lambda$1.run(DetoxActionsDispatcher.kt:64)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.wix.detox.adapters.server.ActionsExecutor$1.run(DetoxActionsDispatcher.kt:50)
12-20 18:29:18.653 10124 10240 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
12-20 18:29:18.658 10124 10240 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 10124 SIG: 9
```

We are aware that technically RN 0.66 is not supported by Detox just yet, but this seems to be something quite specific so we decided to investigate more. We've also noticed that it was only happening when Proguard is enabled (in release mode).

Answer (score 0):

We've found that the culprit were missing Proguard rules:

```
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
```

These were originally part of RN but they were removed: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/30514

Also I don't understand why these are not documented here: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/examples/demo-react-native/android/app/proguard-rules.pro